# SQL Server 2008 syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following as a part of a `SELECT` statement:

```
ISNULL(c.FirstName,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(c.LastName,'') as CustomerName,
CAST(isnull(lr.ReservationNames,'') as nvarchar(2000)) as HolderName
```

I wonder if there is a way to verify if this part is empty

```
CAST(isnull(lr.ReservationNames,'') as nvarchar(2000))
```

How can I assign `CustomerName` to it or in worse case scenario `c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName` ?

Thanks

`lr` is one of the `JOIN` tables in the `SELECT` obviously...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
CAST(isnull(lr.ReservationNames, ISNULL(c.FirstName,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(c.LastName,'')
           ) as nvarchar(2000)
    ) as HolderName
```

Comment: It was staring me in the face but I am on this for so long that could not see it. Thanks man.